# What is the reasoning for the level-of-obligation requirements?

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory

I remember learning that the reason for the rule that a non obligated person cannot do a mitzvah on behalf of an obligated person is because it's more difficult for the obligated person. What is the source for this?

Comment: Are you asking for a source for the idea that it’s more difficult for an obligated person, or a source that that is the reason that one who is not obligated cannot fulfill a mitzvah on behalf of one who is?

Comment: the problem is that the reason is for גדול המצוו ועושה but not for the second din

Comment: Isn't the reason because he cannot be shaliach for this ?... (Something like in Qidushin 41b) Anyway, Rosh Hashana 29a could be a good point of start.

Answer (score 1):

The source that someone cannot do a mitzvah for someone who is not obligated is (very timeously!) a mishna in Rosh haShana 29a (or 3:8)

> Anyone who is not obligated in something, cannot fulfill the obligation
>   for others.

I am not aware of a source connecting this to the source in Avodah Zara which @Shmuel linked to, that it is considered greater to do a mitzvah if one is obligated.

In other words, the connection is false. (However, I would be happy to hear of a source connecting them if someone knows of one.)

Comment: You cannot see it, but I already answered this on the basis of berachot 20b.   But this is called reason

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: I answered the same answer but from an other Gemara. But people said me that this is a source for the law, not for the reason, so I cancelled it. This question is perhaps a result of a mistaken condensation of two formally different topics